# Data caching vs NoSQL

Tags: mongodb, caching

Currently for my project I am storing most frequently reusable data in memory cache(web server itself). it is same as ASP.net traditional classic approach . 
I read a lot article about NoSQL. Now I am thinking to put cached item into NoSQL(mongo or redis) instead of in-memory .

My primary goal is to improve the performance. Can anyone suggest will this approach give some performance improvement ?

Comment: Why would you cache something to disk? That won't improve performance. And, I wouldn't recommend using a disk-backed database for storing temporary cached data on the same machine that is running your application as they will be competing for resources.

Answer (score 1):

First of all redis is in memory (but persistent to disk) database, so your data is actually in memory (and actually this is why it is so fast). Second, it is impossible to tell whether your approach will give you any result.

The best think you can do so far is to implement some crude approach and benchmark it on your real or close to real load and dataset. Also before looking for a way to improve performance, it is nice to locate the bottleneck and to know whether it is worth of implementing.